# Difference between participal adjective and relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses, participles, participial-phrases, deverbal-adjectives

I saw someone explained that participal adjectives have the same function as relative clauses. If that is correct, what is the difference between them?

for examples,

> 1. a bill requiring approval of the committee
> 2. a bill that requires approval of the committee

1 is a participal adjective, 2 is a relative clause.

Do those sentence have the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, they do have the same meaning, and in general this is true when there is a participle corresponding to  a relative clause, as here. There's no particular reason to call them participial "adjectives", though; they're just straightforward participial verb phrases.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you. So can I think there's not even a slight difference?

Comment: 1. and 2. are similar semantically. The difference lies in the structure of the subordinate clauses. They both modify "bill", but they belong to different clause types. In 1. "requiring approval of the committee" is a gerund-participial clause (**not** a participial adjective!), while in 2. it's a relative clause.

Comment: @BillJ I thought that is a participal adjective. I didn't know that is a gerund- participal clause. Thank you BillJ!

Comment: The difference is this: Both can be spoken but no decent editor would allow "that [third-person verb]" for no reason when "verb+ing" can be used.

Comment: @Lambie disagree, i think it depends on context and style.

Comment: @Carly Have you been a magazine editor? When a that is not required, it is removed.

Answer (score 1):

The two are identical in meaning; the difference is solely stylistic, though for me, the participial construction makes for tighter prose. The phrase "requiring the approval of the committee" is, however, neither a clause nor a gerund-participle, a term the Cambridge Grammar employs to remind us all that English doesn't really have a gerund, but still requires that the verb form be used as a noun.

Comment: Cambridge Grammar stats "requiring the approval of the committee" is a participle clause by virtue itself has no overt subject  but an understood subject is retrievable from the subject of the main clause.

Answer (score 0):

A full relative clause has a tense while "requiring" in "requiring approval" (reduced clause/participial-gerund clause or whatever you call it) is a non-finite.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of another example

> "a boy eating food" versus "a boy that eats food"

semantically the former suggests that he is actively engaged in eating whereas the latter more generally that he does engage at times in the activity of eating food (perhaps hinting that he is presently, but less definitively than as stated in the former).